# React: Remove certain html elements from string and normalize

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React app. I also have a **string** that represents a div and this div contains other elements, such as `input`, `img`, `div`, etc. I would like to display this string as HTML using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (which I know is very dangerous). But before I do that, I would like to remove certain elements from the string that correspond to certain tags, such as `img`, `svg` to name a few. What is the way to accomplish this?

BONUS:
Each of these elements might have class, id and/or other attributes. It would be nice to remove these attributes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove certain tags, use DOMParser to turn the string into a document, then use `querySelectorAll` to select all the tags you don't want and `.remove()` them.

To remove all attributes from all elements too, change the `querySelectorAll` to select all elements, and iterate over their `.attributes`.

```js
const str = `
<main class="foo">
  <input>
  <img>
  <div>div</div>
  <section id="thesection" class="sectionclass">
    <img>
    <span>span</span>
  </setion>
</main>
`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const tagsToRemove = 'input, img, div';
for (const elm of doc.querySelectorAll('*')) {
  if (elm.matches(tagsToRemove)) {
    elm.remove();
  }
  for (const attrib of [...elm.attributes]) {
    elm.removeAttribute(attrib.name);
  }
}
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```